# Identity and Credential in different tables. How to login user?

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, zend-db

I'm using Zend Framework.

I save users information in two tables. 
I have one table for his basic information and password, and in the other table I save his e-mails.
He can login with any e-mail.

My question is how should I extend Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable so that I can allow this?

I prefer not to use table views.

**[edit]**

I found a solution.  What worked for me:

```
class My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
protected function _authenticateCreateSelect()
{
    // build credential expression
    if (empty($this->_credentialTreatment) || (strpos($this->_credentialTreatment, '?') === false)) {
        $this->_credentialTreatment = '?';
    }

    $credentialExpression = new Zend_Db_Expr(
        '(CASE WHEN ' .
        $this->_zendDb->quoteInto(
            $this->_zendDb->quoteIdentifier($this->_credentialColumn, true)
            . ' = ' . $this->_credentialTreatment, $this->_credential
            )
        . ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '
        . $this->_zendDb->quoteIdentifier(
            $this->_zendDb->foldCase('zend_auth_credential_match')
            )
        );

    // get select


   //$dbSelect = clone $this->getDbSelect();
   $mdl = new My_Model_Db_Table_Users();
   $dbSelect = $mdl->select();
   $dbSelect = $dbSelect->setIntegrityCheck(false);
   $dbSelect = $dbSelect->from(array('u' => $this->_tableName), array('*', $credentialExpression));
   $dbSelect = $dbSelect->joinInner(array('ue' => 'users_emails'), 'ue.id_user = u.user_id', array('user_email'));
   $dbSelect = $dbSelect->where('ue.' .  $this->_zendDb->quoteIdentifier($this->_identityColumn, true) . ' = ?', $this->_identity);

   return $dbSelect;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained what did it for me in the question.

But, to repeat, easiest for me was to change `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable::_authenticateCreateSelect()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a method named `Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable::getDbSelect` returns `Zend_Db_Select` object.
Call it and then you can join those two tables.

Hope this help.

Regards,
Ahmed B.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already found a solution, I changed _authenticateCreateSelect(), it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate method.

Extend the Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable class.

```
class My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable {
    public function setDbSelect($select) {
        $this->_dbSelect = $select;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Create instance of your new adapter

```
$authAdapter = new My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
    $this->dbTable->getAdapter()
    , 'Users'
    , 'Users.username'
    , 'Users.password'
);
```

In your Application_Model_DbTable_Users class, create a method that returns the select object with the joined tables.

```
public function getSelectAuth() {
    $select = $this
        ->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('SystemPeopleJoined' => $this->_name)
        , array(
            'id'
            , 'person_id'
            , 'system_role_id'
            , 'created_on'
            , 'expires_on'
        )
    )
    ->joinInner(
        'People'
        , 'People.id = SystemPeopleJoined.person_id'
        , array(
            'first_name' => 'first_name'
            , 'last_name' => 'last_name'
            , 'name' => "CONCAT_WS(' ', `People`.`first_name`, `People`.`last_name`)"
    )
    return $select;
}
```

Set the select object in your adapter

```
$select = $this->dbTable->getSelectAuth();

$authAdapter
    ->setDbSelect($select)
    ->setIdentity($params['username'])
    ->setCredential($params['password'])
    ->setCredentialTreatment("SHA1(?)")
;
```